# How many times should I run a solvent extration experiment through?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, extraction

For advanced higher chemistry project, I am extracting cinnamaldehyde from cinnamon via first steam distillation and then solvent extraction using hexane. I'll be adding sodium chloride to the water/cinnamaldehyde mixture. I'm not sure how many times I should run the solvent extraction or if there is a calculation for it.

Comment: Do three extractions, evaporate the hexane, weigh residue. Do 3 more extractions of the aqueous layer, evaporate hexane and weigh. Compare the weights to get an idea of the efficiency of the extraction. If first much greater than the second, then the extraction was efficient. Use the same volume of hexane in each extraction.